# How to get response using jQuery when a html form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, blobstore, blobstorage

I am using BlobStore to save an image. I have a jsp Page. Code for that page is following:

```
 <%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
 <%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>
 <%
 BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
 %>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
   <head>
     <meta name="description" content="My web page" />
    <title>My Web</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mainpage.js"></script>
   </head>

<body>
            <form method="post" id="upload_img_form" name="upload_img_form" action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/imagedao") %>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="upload_img_form_input" name="upload_img_form_input" type="file">
                <input id="upload_img_submit" type="submit" name="upload_img_submit" value="Upload >>" />
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

in jquery-mainpage.js i have the following code:

```
 $("#upload_img_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var upload_img_val = $("#upload_img_form_input").val();
        if(upload_img_val == ''){
                alert('Please choose a file!');
        }else{
            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: url_to_blobstore,
               data: {upload_img_form_input:upload_img_val},
               success: function(result) {
                 console.log('upload_img_form result: '+result);
            }
         });
       }
});
```

i am getting the following exception:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:71)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.readTillFirstBoundary(MimeMultipart.java:244)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parse(MimeMultipart.java:181)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.getCount(MimeMultipart.java:109)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:145)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:111)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:141)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
```

Why am i getting this exception. Is there something wrong with code.
I want to get response when this form is submitted. All jQuery code is in jquery-mainpage.js. Is there any jQuery method which can give me response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: turn the submit into a <a> and execute your javascript function from there.

Comment: there are a number of jQuery file upload plugins. Use one of those..easy to find in google

Comment: what do you mean by a "reponse"? if you're talking about the page response, that's not possible since the page reloads. if you're talking about responding to a sumbit event, just add a submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is have access to the response on the client side script, just submit the form with jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

the response callback has access to the response.

Or you can use the full Forms plugin to manage your form submissions from the client-side:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: you can't send files using AJAX